# Product on Greatest integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove the following equality: $\left[\frac{[x]}{n}\right] = \left[\frac{x}{n} \right]$, if $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I did it:
$$h = \left[\frac{[x]}{n}\right] \rightarrow h\leq \frac{x}{n}< h + 1$$
For definition of greatest integer:
$$h \leq \left[\frac{x}{n} \right] $$
How to prove: $h \geq \left[\frac{x}{n} \right]  $

Comment: Shouldn't your first implication have $\frac{[x]}n$ instead of $\frac xn$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** ${x-[x] \over n}<{1 \over n}$ and ${[x] \over n} \in \mathbb Q$.